# Talend tExtractRegexFields match after comma syntax

Tags: regex, talend

I'm trying to extract everything in a string after the first comma, using the `tExtractRegexFields` component.

I'm splitting strings in an address field `(Address_1)` to a second address field `(Address_2)`.

On `regexr.com`, the following syntax works perfectly: `,[\s\S]*$`

In order to comply with Talend's escape sequences, I changed that syntax to 
`,[\\s\\S]*$`. That solved the error, but the code doesn't appear to match on anything, since nothing is split from `Address_1` to `Address_2`.

What's wrong? Does this syntax not work in `Talend`? Are there alternate `Regex` solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To slipt string using tExtractRegexFields use grouping regex so each group will be delivered to a column, i used this regex and it works fine `"^(.*)[,]([^,]*)$"`, this is the job: (my input string: `"123 North Drive,PO Box 1,Miami, FL 55555-5555"` )

[image]

Comment: For me, this selected and split off everything before the last comma.

For instance, the string "123 North Drive,PO Box 1,Miami, FL 55555-5555" was split into

ADDRESS 1: 123 North Drive,PO Box 1,Miami, FL 55555-5555
ADDRESS 2: 123 North Drive,PO Box 1,Miami

Comment: @StephenDvorak Updated answer !

Comment: Same result as last time.

Comment: @StephenDvorak Strange ! please make sure that you use the new regex `"^(.*)[,]([^,]*)$"` as you can see it works as requested !